# How to use scope in nested functions in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, scope, nested-function

I have trouble using `scope` in nested functions. My code is below and also errors is stated in the code. How can I pass `scope` to nested functions?

```
this.store_1.load({
    params  :{start:0, limit:20},
    callback: function(records, operation, success)
    {
        this.store_2.load({
            params      : {argID: argID},
            callback    : function(records, operation, success) {

                var my_data = this.store_2.data.items[0].data;  

                this.my_rowExpander = new Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander({
                    tpl : new Ext.Template(template_str)
                });

                this.MyDetailGraph = this.getMyGraph(graphDataArr);

                this.MyDetailSummaryPanel = new Ext.Panel({ 
                        html    : this.getMyDetailSummary_Template(arg1, arg2, arg3),
                        title   : 'Title'
                });

                this.myPagingBBar = new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                      pageSize      : 20,
                      buttonAlign   : 'center',
                      store         : this.store_1,
                      doRefresh     : function(){
                            this.store.load({ // if I use this.store_1.load gives error this.store_1 is undefined
                                params  :{start:0, limit:20},
                                callback: function(records, operation, success)
                                {   
                                    // here gives error -->  this.updateDetailGraphValue is not a function
                                    this.updateDetailGraphValue(arg1, this.MyDetailGraph, arg2);
                                    // here must be an error like above
                                    this.updateDetailSummaryPanelValue(this.MyDetailSummaryPanel, arg1, arg2, arg3);
                                }
                            });
                      }
                });

                this.MyDetailGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    store       : this.store_1,
                    bbar        : this.myPagingBBar,
                    plugins     : this.my_rowExpander,
                    columns     :[
                                    this.my_rowExpander,
                                    {header: 'header1'},
                                    {header: 'header2'},
                                    {header: 'header3'},
                                    {header: 'header4'}
                                 ]
                });

                argPanel.items.insert(0, this.MyDetailGraph);

                argPanel.items.insert(1, this.MyDetailSummaryPanel);

                argPanel.items.insert(2, this.MyDetailGrid);

                argPanel.doLayout();
            },
            scope       : this
        });
    }, 
    scope : this
});

this.updateDetailGraphValue = function(argMainPanel, argGraph, argDataArray)
{
        this.graph = this.getDetailGraph(argDataArray);
        argMainPanel.remove(argGraph, true);
        argMainPanel.items.insert(0, this.graph);
        argMainPanel.doLayout();
};

this.updateDetailSummaryPanelValue = function(argPanel, arg1, arg2, arg3)
{
        argPanel.update(this.getDetailSummary_Template(arg1, arg2, arg3));
        argPanel.doLayout();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `this` in first load and I have defined a global scope which is `myGlobalScope` then I used `myGlobalScope` in others:

```
this.store_1.load({
    params  :{start:0, limit:20},
    scope: this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success)
    {

    var myGlobalScope = this; // I have defined this global scope


        this.store_2.load({
            params      : {argID: argID},
            scope   : myGlobalScope, // use myGlobalScope instead of this
            callback    : function(records, operation, success) {

                var my_data = this.store_2.data.items[0].data;  

                this.my_rowExpander = new Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander({
                    tpl : new Ext.Template(template_str)
                });

                this.MyDetailGraph = this.getMyGraph(graphDataArr);

                this.MyDetailSummaryPanel = new Ext.Panel({ 
                        html    : myGlobalScope.getMyDetailSummary_Template(arg1, arg2, arg3), // use myGlobalScope instead of this
                        title   : 'Title'
                });

                this.myPagingBBar = new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                      pageSize      : 20,
                      buttonAlign   : 'center',
                      store         : this.store_1,
                      doRefresh     : function(){
                            this.store.load({ // if I use this.store_1.load gives error this.store_1 is undefined
                                params  :{start:0, limit:20},
                                scope   : this,
                                callback:  function innerCB(records, operation, success) {   
                    myGlobalScope.updateDetailGraphValue(arg1, this.MyDetailGraph, arg2); // use myGlobalScope instead of this
                        myGlobalScope.updateDetailSummaryPanelValue(this.MyDetailSummaryPanel, arg1, arg2, arg3); // use myGlobalScope instead of this
                }
                            });
                      }
                });

                this.MyDetailGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    store       : this.store_1,
                    bbar        : this.myPagingBBar,
                    plugins     : this.my_rowExpander,
                    columns     :[
                                    this.my_rowExpander,
                                    {header: 'header1'},
                                    {header: 'header2'},
                                    {header: 'header3'},
                                    {header: 'header4'}
                                 ]
                });

                argPanel.items.insert(0, this.MyDetailGraph);

                argPanel.items.insert(1, this.MyDetailSummaryPanel);

                argPanel.items.insert(2, this.MyDetailGrid);

                argPanel.doLayout();
            }
        });
    }
});

this.updateDetailGraphValue = function(argMainPanel, argGraph, argDataArray)
{
        this.graph = this.getDetailGraph(argDataArray);
        argMainPanel.remove(argGraph, true);
        argMainPanel.items.insert(0, this.graph);
        argMainPanel.doLayout();
};

this.updateDetailSummaryPanelValue = function(argPanel, arg1, arg2, arg3)
{
        argPanel.update(this.getDetailSummary_Template(arg1, arg2, arg3));
        argPanel.doLayout();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below. But I dunno I it will work. You haven't defined <strike>any</strike> the scope for the last callback <strike>in your callbacks</strike> and your are using `this` all the times. It is only a matter of time when you end up with scope problems. Consider mapping `this` to a local variable like `me`.

```
this.store_1.load({
    params  :{start:0, limit:20},
    scope: this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success)
    {
        this.store_2.load({
            params      : {argID: argID},
            scope: this,
            callback    : function(records, operation, success) {

                var my_data = this.store_2.data.items[0].data;  

                this.my_rowExpander = new Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander({
                    tpl : new Ext.Template(template_str)
                });

                this.MyDetailGraph = this.getMyGraph(graphDataArr);

                this.MyDetailSummaryPanel = new Ext.Panel({ 
                        html    : this.getMyDetailSummary_Template(arg1, arg2, arg3),
                        title   : 'Title'
                });

                function innerCB(records, operation, success) {   
                    // here gives error -->  this.updateDetailGraphValue is not a function
                    this.updateDetailGraphValue(arg1, this.MyDetailGraph, arg2);
                    // here must be an error like above
                    this.updateDetailSummaryPanelValue(this.MyDetailSummaryPanel, arg1, arg2, arg3);
                }

                this.myPagingBBar = new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                      pageSize      : 20,
                      buttonAlign   : 'center',
                      store         : this.store_1,
                      doRefresh     : function(){
                            this.store.load({ // if I use this.store_1.load gives error this.store_1 is undefined
                                params  :{start:0, limit:20},
                                scope: this,
                                callback: innerCB
                            });
                      }
                });

                this.MyDetailGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    store       : this.store_1,
                    bbar        : this.myPagingBBar,
                    plugins     : this.my_rowExpander,
                    columns     :[
                                    this.my_rowExpander,
                                    {header: 'header1'},
                                    {header: 'header2'},
                                    {header: 'header3'},
                                    {header: 'header4'}
                                 ]
                });

                argPanel.items.insert(0, this.MyDetailGraph);

                argPanel.items.insert(1, this.MyDetailSummaryPanel);

                argPanel.items.insert(2, this.MyDetailGrid);

                argPanel.doLayout();
            }
        });
    }
});

this.updateDetailGraphValue = function(argMainPanel, argGraph, argDataArray)
{
        this.graph = this.getDetailGraph(argDataArray);
        argMainPanel.remove(argGraph, true);
        argMainPanel.items.insert(0, this.graph);
        argMainPanel.doLayout();
};

this.updateDetailSummaryPanelValue = function(argPanel, arg1, arg2, arg3)
{
        argPanel.update(this.getDetailSummary_Template(arg1, arg2, arg3));
        argPanel.doLayout();
};
```

Comment: I tried as you stated, it still gives error here:
`this.updateDetailGraphValue(arg1, this.MyDetailGraph, arg2);`

Comment: @vtokmak I made an edit. Normally this will work but as it is placed within a already nested callback it could also fail. But I think it is worth a try.

Comment: still I can not reach `this.updateDetailGraphValue` function which is in `function innerCB`. I get same error. It is hard to give a scope to functions :/

Comment: @vtokmak I recommend you to restart with small steps. Use console.log to inspect each scope within each function. That should help you to indicate where you loose it. When you nest that deep you should use a mapped scoped instead of this. That preserve most problems. Basically it is impossible to use this all the time.

Comment: @vtokmak Like what I said :) But it is not a global scope, just a mapped scope. Most common is `var me = this;` That's what I meant with *Consider mapping this to a local variable like me.*

Comment: yes I came up with it so much using like `var me = this;` after your comment :) Thx a lot! ;)